# How to filter array of objects with nested arrays of objects based on other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

Sample code.

```
const cards = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "J",
        tag: [
          {
            "colour": "red"
          },
          {
            "colour": "yello"
          },
          {
            "colour": "blue"
          },
          {
            "colour": "white"
          },
        ],
        size: [
          {
            "name": "small"
          },
          {
            "name": "medium"
          },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "S",
        tag: [
          {
            "colour": "red"
          },
          {
            "colour": "green"
          },
          {
            "colour": "black"
          },
        ],
        size: [
          {
            "name": "small"
          },
          {
            "name": "medium"
          },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "K",
        tag: [
          {
            "colour": "green"
          },
          {
            "colour": "purple"
          },
          {
            "colour": "brown"
          },
          {
            "colour": "white"
          },
        ],
        size: [
          {
            "name": "large"
          },
        ],
    }
];
```

Test arrays

```
const sizeArray = ["medium", "small"];
const tagArray = ["red", "black"];
```

I want the filtered array of objects to only include the second object in this example. Filtering only those who match all criteria leaving me with a new array of objects.

I've tried with .filter, .some, .includes and no luck looking over many other answers to similar questions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you describe what you want and what the desired outcome looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Since you need to filter the result which contains all `sizeArray` and `tagArray` in `size` and `tag` array respectively.

```js
const cards = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "J",
    tag: [
      {
        colour: "red",
      },
      {
        colour: "yello",
      },
      {
        colour: "blue",
      },
      {
        colour: "white",
      },
    ],
    size: [
      {
        name: "small",
      },
      {
        name: "medium",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "S",
    tag: [
      {
        colour: "red",
      },
      {
        colour: "green",
      },
      {
        colour: "black",
      },
    ],
    size: [
      {
        name: "small",
      },
      {
        name: "medium",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "K",
    tag: [
      {
        colour: "green",
      },
      {
        colour: "purple",
      },
      {
        colour: "brown",
      },
      {
        colour: "white",
      },
    ],
    size: [
      {
        name: "large",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const sizeArray = ["medium", "small"];
const tagArray = ["red", "black"];

const result = cards.filter(({ tag, size }) =>
    sizeArray.every((s) => size.some((si) => si.name === s)) &&
    tagArray.every((t) => tag.some((ta) => ta.colour === t))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Done. Thanks again, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

As you `filter` the main array, you want to make sure at least one of the `tag` values is in the `tagArray` and at least one of the `size` values is in the `sizeArray`. This can be achieved using `includes`.

```js
const cards=[{id:"1",name:"J",tag:[{colour:"red"},{colour:"yello"},{colour:"blue"},{colour:"white"}],size:[{name:"small"},{name:"medium"}]},{id:"2",name:"S",tag:[{colour:"red"},{colour:"green"},{colour:"black"}],size:[{name:"small"},{name:"medium"}]},{id:"3",name:"K",tag:[{colour:"green"},{colour:"purple"},{colour:"brown"},{colour:"white"}],size:[{name:"large"}]}];

const sizeArray = ["medium", "small"];
const tagArray = ["red", "black"];

const filtered = cards.filter((card) => {
  return (
    card.tag.some((tag) => tagArray.includes(tag.colour)) &&
    card.size.some((size) => sizeArray.includes(size.name))
  );
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Note that `includes` isn't super efficient, but I'm assuming you're not working with tons of data here. If your `sizeArray` or `tagArray` are especially large, you could look into something like the `Set` object for hash table efficiency.

Comment: Needs to be tagArray.every && sizeArray.every in order to only return second object as op expects

Comment: Sure it would if you test the filter arrays that every value is found in the object. See answer below using that approch

Comment: Thank you, Nick, that was helpful. I did need it to return only the objects that matched as Charlie commented. 

I will take your advice on the hash table efficiency as the DB dataset will likely be large.

Thanks again.